# ASP.NET Core keep-alive to ESP32

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket, microcontroller

I would like to have ASP.NET Core based website with communication to ESP32 (microcontroller with program based on Arduino code) which would have keep-alive connection. Something like serial-port without cable over network. I figured out that websocket might work and be the best solution (or not?). ESP32 doesn't support SignalR so I have to go raw websocket. I found only middle-ware solutions without support to be called from controller.

Idea is: Keep-alive connection between ESP32 and ASP.NET Core website. User can go to website and trigger action (from browser/api) which will send data to ESP32. Website is public-part. Browser and ESP32 are closed parts (I mean.. no public ip address). Also I would like to send data immediately after action is triggered. It would be nice if ESP32 would receive data within 3 seconds.

Is websocket correct idea? Can you show me or direct me how to send data from action to websocket client? I couldnt find enough informations how to make it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Websocket I finally used TCP via TcpListener running as IHostedService. I made Singleton class with Queue to queue messages from API calls. In IHostedService while cycle I checked if there is any new queue message to send.

ESP32 connected via Wifi using WiFiClient library.

Simple & fast

Comment: Could you please share an example